# Cognos Report re-issues multiple queries instead of doing more local processing, slow report

Tags: cognos-10

I have a Cognos report that I would like to try and speed up if possible. The report takes 4 minutes when I direct the output to HTML (including jumping to the last page to ensure that the whole report is created), 7 minutes when directing output to EXCEL and 8 minutes for a PDF.

The report uses a single Query subject which is associated with a database VIEW. When I select * from the view, the view returns 200 rows in 28 seconds. This is the only query in my report.

I have 2 Cross tabs that are both bound to this one Cognos query. The first crosstab has section breaks on a column "FUNDING REPORT NAME", the second crosstab one does not, instead it summarizes across all FUNDING REPORT NAMES.

I then group the Report Page on two columns, "REPORT GROUP" and "LEGAL ENTITY." This leads to the creation of a separate tab for each distinct pair of values. On each tab, Cognos auto filters and summarizes the data for the current value of REPORT GROUP/LEGAL ENTITY.

[image]

I believe that the report is taking longer than expected because Cognos is executing multiple queries against the view instead of only executing it once. What I would like Cognos to do for performance reasons, is to return all 200 of the rows in the View, store the results locally and then query against these rows to identify the DISTINCT values of REPORT GROUP and LEGAL ENTITY and, within this grouping, summarize the local data within the current FUNDING REPORT NAME. Instead, it issues multiple queries against the view to get this information instead of doing local processing of the small resultset.

In order to get Cognos to identify the distinct values to break on and summarize locally, I tried experimenting with the following property settings:

```
Set "RollUPProcessing" property on Query = Local 

Set "Use Local cache" property On Query = Yes

Set the "Query Process" property on the Data Source object in the Model to "Limited Local"
```

However, these changes seemed to have no  effect on the execution time.

Is there anything that I can do to make this report execute faster? HTML is considerable faster but Excel is the requirement. Is there anything that I can do to spedd up the production of the report when direvcted to Excel?

Here are the 4 Cognos syntax queries that Cognos says it is excuting. There is only one Query in my report that, again returns all rows 200 records, in a VIEW.

```html
select distinct 
   "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REPORT_GROUP"   "Report_group" 
 , "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."LEGAL_ENTTY_NAME"  "Legal_Entity_Name" 
from 
 MYSCHEMA."MLR_ROLL_FWD_V"      "MLR_ROLL_FWD"
 order by 
    "Report_group" asc 
  , "Legal_Entity_Name" asc  
FOR FETCH ONLY
```

```html
select distinct 
  "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."FUNDNG_RPT_NM"  "Funding_Report_Name" 
 ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REPORT_GROUP"   "Report_group" 
 ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."LEGAL_ENTTY_NAME"  "Legal_Entity_Name" 
 from 
  MYSCHEMA."MLR_ROLL_FWD_V"     "MLR_ROLL_FWD"
 order by 
  "Funding_Report_Name" asc  
FOR FETCH ONLY
```

```html
select 
  "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REPORT_GROUP"    "Report_groupkey" 
 ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."LEGAL_ENTTY_NAME"   "Legal_Entity_Namekey" 
 
 ,case  
  when "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" <> 9999 then 
   'Service Year ' || "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" 
  else 'Total' 
 end  "levelkey" 

 ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."YEAR_QUARTER"       "Year_Quarterkey" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."BEG_BAL_AMT")      "Beginning_Gross_Balance" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_CSH_AMT")     "Cash_Collection" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_BILLD_AMT")    "Current_Billing_AMT" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_UNDR_OVR_PAYMT_AMT")  "Over_Under_Payment_AMT" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_RECVBL_MANL_ADJ_AMT")  "RXP_Adjustment_AMT"  
 ,sum ("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_RECVBL_BUMP_UP_AMT")  "RXP_Bump_Up_Adjustment_AMT" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."PYE_RECVBL_BUMP_UP_REVSL_AMT") "RXP_Bump_Up_Reversal_AMT" 
 ,sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."GL_REBATE_RECVBL_AMT")   "Ending_Balance__Net_" 
 
 from 
  MYSCHEMA."MLR_ROLL_FWD_V" "MLR_ROLL_FWD"
 
 group by 
    "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REPORT_GROUP"
   ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."LEGAL_ENTTY_NAME", 

   case  
    when "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" <> 9999 
     then 'Service Year ' || "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" 
   else 'Total' 
  end 

  ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."YEAR_QUARTER" 

FOR FETCH ONLY
```

```html
select 
  "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REPORT_GROUP" "  Report_groupkey" 
 ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."LEGAL_ENTTY_NAME"   "Legal_Entity_Namekey" 

 , case  when "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" <> 9999
   then 'Service Year ' || "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" 
  else 
   'Total' 
  end  "levelkey" 

  , "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."YEAR_QUARTER"       "Year_Quarterkey" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."BEG_BAL_AMT")      "Beginning_Gross_Balance" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_CSH_AMT")      "Cash_Collection" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_BILLD_AMT")     "Current_Billing_AMT" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_UNDR_OVR_PAYMT_AMT")   "Over_Under_Payment_AMT" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_RECVBL_MANL_ADJ_AMT")   "RXP_Adjustment_AMT" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REBATE_RECVBL_BUMP_UP_AMT")   "RXP_Bump_Up_Adjustment_AMT" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."PYE_RECVBL_BUMP_UP_REVSL_AMT")  "RXP_Bump_Up_Reversal_AMT" 
  , sum("MLR_ROLL_FWD"."GL_REBATE_RECVBL_AMT")    "Ending_Balance__Net_" 
 
 from 
  MYSCHEMA."MLR_ROLL_FWD_V" "MLR_ROLL_FWD"
 
 group by 
    "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."REPORT_GROUP"
  , "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."LEGAL_ENTTY_NAME"

  , case  when "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" <> 9999 
   then 'Service Year ' || "MLR_ROLL_FWD"."SERVICE_YEAR" 
 else 'Total' end 

 ,"MLR_ROLL_FWD"."YEAR_QUARTER" 

FOR FETCH ONLY
```

One huge concern is that Query 3 and 4 are identical. You would think that if I am binding 2 crosstabs to the same Query that this would not cause the SQL to be run twice.

Comment: What's the data source? Is it CQM or DQM? If there is a Master-Detail relationship you can also expect separate queries for the each of the details. Also, have you tried setting the queries to database-only processing? Pushing more work to the database could speed up performance.
It's also expected that PDF and Excel take longer to render since it's doing all of the data instead of just the first page

Comment: CQM. Yes, ther eis a Master-Detail relationship. No I didn't try database-only because I was trying to recduce the number of times it hit the database. I'll try it for grins. HTML took 4 minutes incouding paging to the last page (END).